# Laravel add Sortby Filter on Search results by using Select orderby rate desc

Tags: php, sorting, laravel-5

I can't add sorting select on my search result. I can't make it work.
I've added if statement to sort by select statement like this:

I've tried to add an if statement to sort manually by selecting but, no results changing.

Am I missing something or how do I fix it?

```
public function search(Request $request){
    $cityKey = $request->cityKey;
    $key = $request->key;


        $doctors = Doctor_list::where('speciality_title', 'LIKE', '%' . $key . '%')->
        where('location', 'LIKE', '%' . $cityKey . '%')->
        orWhere('doctors_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $key . '%')->
        where('location', 'LIKE', '%' . $cityKey . '%')->
        orWhere('speciality_type', 'LIKE', '%' . $key . '%')->
        where('location', 'LIKE', '%' . $cityKey . '%')->get();


    If ($request->get('sortBy') === 'rate'){
        dd($doctors->orderBy('rate', 'desc'));
    }
    return view('healthflex.search', compact('doctors'));
}

<select name="sortBy" class="select"> //THIS IS SELECT STATEMENT
    <option>choose</option>
    <option class="sorting" value="rate}">rate</option>
    <option class="sorting">Popular</option>
    <option class="sorting">Ohirgi</option>
```

Comment: Why not use the orderBy within the mysql query ? Also I do not thin Laravel has orderBy outside Elequent..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$doctors = Doctor_list::where('speciality_title', 'LIKE', '%' . $key . '%')->
    where('location', 'LIKE', '%' . $cityKey . '%')->
    orWhere('doctors_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $key . '%')->
    where('location', 'LIKE', '%' . $cityKey . '%')->
    orWhere('speciality_type', 'LIKE', '%' . $key . '%')->
    where('location', 'LIKE', '%' . $cityKey . '%')
    ->orderBy($request->input('sortBy', 'id'), 'desc');
```

if you don't even apply the sort if the sortBy value is not passed in request you may do instead

```
    ->where('location', 'LIKE', '%' . $cityKey . '%')
    ->when($sortBy = $request->input('sortBy'), function($query) use($sortBy){
        $query->orderBy($sortBy , 'desc');
    });
```

Now you can return the result

```
 return view('healthflex.search', compact('doctors'));
```

Comment: thanks for it. Now, it is sorting by deafult without selecting. I was looking for sort after search results.

Comment: It's better sorting within the query rather than getting the collection and applying sort in it. as I did above you may rely on a default sort option or sort based on the parameter you have passed via request. if you don't even apply the sort action if there is no sort option passed in the request just wrap it in the "when" condition. I have updated the answer above to make it use of when . but in my opinion both are almost same